# How can understand a constant variable in memory. C++

Tags: c++, pointers, constants

If I have a constant variable, is it stored in a seperate memory space from non-constant variables? I have encounter some odd in this program.

```
    //--------assign a const value to non-const value-------
const int cst_a = 5;
int* ptra = const_cast<int*>(&cst_a);

cout<<&cst_a<<" "<<ptra<<endl; // same address

*ptra = 6;

cout<<*ptra<<" "<<cst_a<<endl; // same address with different value

//--------assign a non-const value to const value-------

int b = 50;
const int* cst_ptr_b = &b;

cout<<cst_ptr_b<<" "<<&b<<endl; // also same address

b = 55;
cout<<b<<" "<<*cst_ptr_b<<endl; // same address with same value

return 0;
```

In the first case, &cst_a and ptra has the same memory address, but their value can change seperately.  In the second case, cst_ptr_b and &b are also same address, but their value change symetrically. Why?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It may be stored in a memory area that can't be modified. Because of this, your `const_cast` results in undefined behavior.

Comment: how about the cases like `int i = 5; const int c = i;`; I think in that case `c` will not be stored in read only region.

Comment: @iammilind: I did say it **may** be stored in memory that can't be modified. A case like you mentioned may prevent that. I don't believe there's any guarantee that a constant will ever be stored in non-modifiable memory. Regardless, it is undefined behavior according to the standard.

Comment: @iammilind: A modern compiler (e.g. GCC 4.5) _will_ detect that `c` is always initialized with the value 5 (in optimized builds). But is also aggressively optimizes out variables. I.e. it may not store 5 in memory at all, if it can avoid it.

Comment: @MSalters, that was just an rough example. How about `fun(int i) { const int c = i; }` ; the point is that `c` is always dependent on `i`, so in such sense it's questionable that `c` is stored in read only region.

Comment: @iammilind: Well, in that case the compiler can trivially detect that `c` is't used at all in its scope. The problem with such examples is that they're typically so simple that optimizers can always optimize them.

Answer (score 0):

Congrats, `*ptra = 6;` is undefined behaviour. :)
You are not allowed to write to a constant value, not through pointer, not through reference. This is because a constant object might (and most likely will) be put into the constant memory area.

Comment: how to understand "might (and most likely will)"?

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what value you store in the constant.

```
const int c = 5; // This will be stored in read only area
```

Trying to modify read only area is Undefined Behavior (which you have done in your code using `const_cast`)

Other scenario is,

```
int i = 5;
const int c = i;  // This is stored in normal read/write memory segment
```

Comment: The "other scenario" is better written as `const int c = rnd() % 6;`

Comment: @Kiril, the second scenario suggests that `const c` is modifiable. Because, it's dependent on and assigned a variable value `i` (`i` can be `6`, `10` anything).

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the explicit type casting that is taking place in example #1. C++ let's you do this and since const int* and int* are different types along with the compilers free choice to store constants in either writeable or non-writeable memory makes this undefined behaviour, as said in earlier posts.