# C++ Pointer Confusion

Tags: c++

Please Explain the following code

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    const int x = 10;
    int * ptr;
    ptr = (int *)( &x );    //make the pointer to constant int*
    *ptr = 8;               //change the value of the constant using the pointer.
    //here is the real surprising part
    cout<<"x: "<<x<<endl;          //prints 10, means value is not changed
    cout<<"*ptr: "<<*ptr<<endl;    //prints 8, means value is changed
    cout<<"ptr: "<<(int)ptr<<endl; //prints some address lets say 0xfadc02
    cout<<"&x: "<<(int)&x<<endl;   //prints the same address, i.e. 0xfadc02
    //This means that x resides at the same location ptr points to yet 
    //two different values are printed, I cant understand this.

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: If something is not clear from comments in the code, you should read about "C++ pointers". Just put it in the Gooogle

Comment: `ptr = (int *)( &x );` (followed by `*ptr = 8`) is undefined behavior, asking about the behavior of the program is meaningless.

Comment: @GMan: It's not that line that has undefined behavior, it's the next line that attempts to write to a const qualified object. See references [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1542200/is-using-const-cast-for-read-only-access-to-a-const-object-allowed) .

Comment: What about the code would you like explained?

Comment: g++ throws errors, like it should.

Comment: Same question as http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5987817/how-can-understand-a-constant-variable-in-memory-c/

Comment: @Adam, I have compiled in Visual Studio 2008, its running..

Comment: @Charles: You're right of course, I'm used to questions like these casting and modifying in a single statement. Didn't realize this one was special. ;)

Comment: @Siddiqui : What does that prove, other than that one valid manifestation of undefined behavior is "everything _appears_ okay..."?

Comment: Ok I understand now, thanks to every one..

Comment: @GMan: It think that most people would agree that the line you highlight is "wrong", because it allows the next line to cause UB despite looking relatively innocuous.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
*ptr = 8;
```

This line causes *undefined behavior* because you are modifying the value of a `const` qualified object. Once you have *undefined behavior* anything can happen and it is not possible to reason about the behaviour of the program.

Answer (score 6):

Since `x` is a `const int`, the compiler will most likely, in the places where you use `x`, directly substitute the value that you've initialized with (where possible). So the line in your source code:

```
cout<<"x: "<<x<<endl;
```

will be replaced by this at compile time:

```
cout<<"x: "<<10<<endl;
```

That's why you still see 10 printed.

But as Charles explained, the behaviour is undefined, so anything could happen with code like this.